# Cannot execute body onload function in <body> from Sitemesh

Tags: javascript, onload, sitemesh, document-body

I am trying to create a simple application that includes Sitemesh for decorating the resulting page.

Following is the simple page I am trying to create.

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Creating a simple map</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAXWLpztTcGIDURBKce345XdXtfws5guEs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value=" /resources/js/keydragzoom_packed.js " />"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
                alert("hi");
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            html,
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="init();">
        <h1>Smart Farm Application</h1>
        <p>Time right now is :
            <c:out value="${now}" />
        </p>
        <table border="1" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Google Map API</th>
                <th>Google Chart Section</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <div id="google_map_area" style="width: 500px; height: 800px;"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="scatter_chart_area" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And following is the decorator page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

        <head>
            <title>https://bharatonjava.wordpress.com |
                <decorator:title default="Sitemesh Example" />
            </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="<c:url value=" /resources/assets/css/style.css " />">
            <decorator:head />
        </head>
        <body>
            <table class="mainTable" id="page-container" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="page-header">
                        <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/header.jsp" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="nav-container" colspan="2">
                        <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/navigation.jsp" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="left-nav-container">
                        <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/navigationLeft.jsp" %>
                    </td>
                    <td id="content-container">
                        <decorator:body onLoad="<decorator:getProperty property='body.onLoad' />">
                        </decorator:body>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="page-footer">
                        <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/footer.jsp" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <br /><a href='https://test.com'>test</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

However this is not getting decorated at all. When I request the page from browser I see the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/decorators/layout.jsp(37,12) Attribute onLoad invalid for tag body according to TLD
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.decorator.BaseWebAppDecorator.render(BaseWebAppDecorator.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:84)
```

I can't figure out where I am wrong with the code above. I have spent hours trying to figure this without going anywhere. Has anyone faced this before ?

Comment: Have you tried `onload="init();"` instead of camelCase'ing (`onLoad`) ? Also try right clicking the page to `inspect element` (in Safari / Chrome) to see the code that is actually generated by your page (instead of view source, that just shows the code at runtime) to see if SiteMesh messes up some stuff

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's `onload="init();"` instead of `onLoad="init();"`, that's what raises the Exception, take a look at [onload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

Or you can try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Or

```
body.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

More information at [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, onload still doesn't work. But window.addEventListener("load", init, false); almost works, after addEventListener there are other errors that pop-up like, 1) Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null. This usually happens if we try to run JavaScript before the div is rendered. I am trying to initialize Google Map in the JavaScript section.. any ideas on how to fix this now ?